# Testing a SQLite database on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, unit-testing, junit

I am working on JUnit tests for my Android app which uses a SQLite database. I need to create  a test database which can be manipulated by test cases. The database needs to start in a known configuration and reset for each test case. I figured out that I can use an in-memory database by passing the SQLiteOpenHelper a `null` value as the file name for the database ([see this article for details](http://attakornw.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/using-in-memory-sqlite-database-in-android-tests/)). Now I also want to populate the database table for some of my tests. I have a CSV file on my local file system with some data that I can use for testing. How do I get this data into my SQLite database on an emulator or other device for testing?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Comment: @YaqubAhmad Thanks for the link. I'll try those suggestions tonight or later this weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in CSV import function in the SQLite library code.

However, the [`sqlite3`](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) command-line tool can import CSV files. Once imported, you have a database file that you can just copy to your device with the `adb` tool.
Alternatively, you can use sqlite3's `.dump` command to generate the SQL commands to recreate the database; you then put them into a string array, or put them into a text file read by your test program.

Comment: I assume that the `sqlite3` tool you are referring to will run on my desktop command-line. So if I import the CSV file to a database, then it will be saved in my desktop file system. That amount of by-hand work is fine. Now is there a way to programmatically import that database to a device during testing? I will also need to erase the database (probably in a `tearDown()` method), which shouldn't be difficult with the Android API. The only part I'm not sure about is getting the database on the emulator in the first place.